# SSRS Custom Assembly Permissions issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am trying to create a custom SSRS assembly that formats the style of a report based on the value of an SQL table.

I need to be able to preview this locally and deploy to the reporting server.

This would allow me to roll out style changes to a series of Paginated Reports from a central place.

Example expression: `=ProjectName.ClassName.getItemStyle("Header", "Font-Family")`
The expression parses the values I'm looking for then goes off and returns a value from the SQL table, in this case "Verdana".

I've been through various steps to get this working as far as I have and have now reached a permissions problem. The assembly works fine so long as I don't try to connect to an SQL server.

In which case I receive this error:

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Request for
>   the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission,
>   System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I have tried adding in assembly permissions and editing the rssrvpolicy config file to no avail, but I feel like I am missing something and I'm not too sure I understand the Microsoft documentation on this.

I have also signed the assembly and installed the certificate.

Code I've used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security;
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]

namespace CC_rpt
{   
    public class lib
    {
        public static string getItemStyle(string parse)
        {
            string val;
            val = "1";

            try
            {              
                using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBServer;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
                {
                    var oCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                    oCmd.Connection = oConn;
                    oCmd.CommandText = "select singleValue FROM Table WHERE Column = @Param";
                    oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", parse);
                    val = oCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
            }

            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
            {
                val = e.ToString();
            }

            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

> *OS*: 
>   Windows 7 Enterprise Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
>
> *Visual Studio*:
>   Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017     Version 15.9.13
>
> **Server**
>   SSRS Reporting Services 2016
>
> *Installed Products*:
>   SQL Server Reporting Services 15.0.1528.0     SQL Server Integration Services 15.0.1300.371

.Net libraries I'm primarily trying to use: `System.Data.SqlClient` targeting .Net Framework: 4.6.1

Paths I'm copying the DLL to (Via a post build event)*:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\MSBuild
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Reporting Services C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
>   Services\ReportServer\bin

Assembly security settings: I have signed the assembly created the string key file (pfx) and installed it.

Comment: I should add that the permissions issue isnt an issue connecting to the actual server as I have permissions to CRUD and have tested this prior.

Comment: I cant believe no one has come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Same problem, 30 Firefox Tabs later:

My jurney starts here:
http://bryantlikes.com/WritingCustomCodeInSQLServerReportingServices.aspx

You need to add a CodeGroup to this file:
`c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\rssrvpolicy.config`

Couldn't really get it to work with a Custom Permission Set, so I used FullTrust. Maybe not the cleanest?

My last version of the CodeGroup looks as follows:

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust" Name="DBAccessPermissionCodeGroup" Description="A special code group for my custom assembly.">
    <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\bin\Your_Custom_DLL_Name.dll" />
</CodeGroup>
```

By the way: Check the url of the dll, might seem obvious but yeah, don't ask me how I know..

Then you gotta mark your Methods (and/or maybe Classes?) as `[SecuritySafeCritical]`, because SSRS's Expression thingy runs as SecurityTransparent. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850214/11829240)

If you don't do that, you will get an error that says something like `Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods`

And you also want to add the following Attribute to the Method that uses the SQL Stuff
`[SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]`

If you leave this out, you will get exactly the error you are experiencing.

And in my AssemblyInfo.cs I added
`[assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]`
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/19214614/11829240)

I don't know if it is necessary, but my .dll is signed.

When finished, I enabled TCP/IP in my SQL Server and created a new user (and enabled SQL-Server authentication).

By the way: to debug #Error messages, I used prodcump.
`./procdump.exe -f "" -l -e 1 ReportingServicesService.exe`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump

I hope this helps someone, because that was not funny to research. But now my custom assembly finally works.

My connection string:
`Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=user;Password=pass;`

This PermissionSet did NOT work for me:

```
<PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Name="DBAccessPermissionSet" Description="A special permission set that grants access to Databases.">
  <IPermission class="SqlClientPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
  <IPermission class="SecurityPermission" version="1" Flags="Execution, Assertion" />
</PermissionSet>
```

It somehow also throws the `Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods` Error.

Comment: Wow thankyou very much :) I havnt yet tried this but it makes sense - I've been searching ages too and its a pitty microsoft dont make this clear in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issue with the Visual Studio preview, then the solution from @bergerb is correct but you are looking at different folder/file

1. The folder should be something like
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS
2. The file you need to edit is RSPreviewPolicy.config in the same location
3. Add this code from @bergerb

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust" Name="DBAccessPermissionCodeGroup" Description="A special code group for my custom assembly.">
    <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\bin\Your_Custom_DLL_Name.dll" />
</CodeGroup>
```